# RenderTargetBitmap Image Sliding

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm having a problem with RenderTargetBitmap whenever I render canvas and clear its children and set the rendered bitmap as background of canvas it slide toward bottom right.

can't insert images until 10 reputation :(.

WPF:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="700"
        KeyDown="Window_KeyDown">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
            <Canvas x:Name="Pad">
                <Rectangle Height="100" Width="100" Fill="Red" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10"></Rectangle>
        </Canvas>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

c# code:

```
namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

         public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            RenderTargetBitmap rendrer = new RenderTargetBitmap(Convert.ToInt32(Pad.ActualWidth),                                                    Convert.ToInt32(Pad.ActualHeight), 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
            rendrer.Render(Pad);
            Pad.Background = new ImageBrush(rendrer);
            Pad.Children.Clear();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your primary problem stems from the fact that, due to the 1-pixel border around the `Canvas`, its `VisualOffset` vector is `(1,1)`. Thus, any visual effect, like the background brush, will be applied at that offset. When you render the visual into a bitmap, it captures the present appearance, and then when you set the bitmap as the brush, it gets shifted.

Ironically, one of the easiest ways to fix this is to insert another `<Border/>` element into your XAML:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
  <Border>
    <Canvas x:Name="Pad">
      <Rectangle Height="100" Width="100" Fill="Red" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10"/>
    </Canvas>
  </Border>
</Border>
```

Then the offset caused by the outer `<Border/>` element is handled by the new `<Border/>` element's transform, rather than being applied to the `<Canvas/>` element.

That change alone will *almost* fix your code completely. However, there's one other little artifact that you may still notice: every time you render the visual, it gets just a teensy bit blurrier. This is because the default value for the `Brush` object's `Stretch` property is `Stretch.Fill`, and because your `<Canvas/>` element is not precisely an integral width or height, the bitmap (which necessarily *does* have integral width and height) gets stretched just a teensy bit when rendered. With each iteration, this becomes more and more apparent.

You can fix that by setting the `Stretch` property to `Stretch.None`. At the same time, you'll also want to set the brush's alignment to `Left` and `Top`:

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    RenderTargetBitmap renderer = new RenderTargetBitmap(
        Convert.ToInt32(Pad.ActualWidth), Convert.ToInt32(Pad.ActualHeight), 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
    renderer.Render(Pad);
    ImageBrush brush = new ImageBrush(renderer);
    brush.AlignmentX = AlignmentX.Left;
    brush.AlignmentY = AlignmentY.Top;
    brush.Stretch = Stretch.None;
    Pad.Background = brush;
    Pad.Children.Clear();
}
```

The defaults are `Center`, which again incurs the rounding error and will cause both movement and blurring of the image after repeated iterations of the process.

With the above changes, I found a perfectly stable image, regardless of the number of iterations.

The "wrap in a border" idea came from here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jaimer/2009/07/03/rendertargetbitmap-tips/

On that page you'll find a more general-purpose solution which does not require modification of the actual XAML. In your example above, the "wrap in a border" approach seems like a reasonable work-around, but it is admittedly not as clean as forcing an unadorned context into which you can render the visual, as shown on that blog page.

Answer (score 5):

To avoid any offset problems with drawing a Visual into a RenderTargetBitmap, you may use an intermediate DrawingVisual:

```
var rect = new Rect(Pad.RenderSize);
var visual = new DrawingVisual();

using (var dc = visual.RenderOpen())
{
    dc.DrawRectangle(new VisualBrush(Pad), null, rect);
}

var bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(
    (int)rect.Width, (int)rect.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Default);
bitmap.Render(visual);

Pad.Background = new ImageBrush(bitmap);
Pad.Children.Clear();
```

Note that without setting any further properties of the ImageBrush (like e.g. its Viewport), it will fill the entire area of the Rectangle. For details, see [TileBrush Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/tilebrush-overview).

Comment: Works like a charm. Apparently the DrawingVisual/DrawingContext/VisualBrush ignores the VisualOffset, that will otherwise bother the RenderTargetBitmap.
My code:
            Rect rect = new Rect(new Point(), new Point(control.ActualWidth, control.ActualHeight));
           
            DrawingVisual dv = new DrawingVisual();
            using (DrawingContext ctx = dv.RenderOpen())
            {
                VisualBrush vb = new VisualBrush(control);
                ctx.DrawRectangle(vb, null, rect);
            }