# rendering wpf control to bitmap

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap, rendering

I've got a user control inside a scrollviewer (inside a ControlTemplate) that I want to render to a bitmap. The method to do this is called from a contextmenu on the control itself. The problem I'm having is that when I render the bitmap, it is offset by the amount of horizontaloffset used in the scrollviewer. This is despite the fact that I'm rendering directly from the control, and not the scrollviewer.
I've tried setting the horizontal offset to 0 in the code, but that doesn't work (probably because the display needs to refresh before it takes effect - and I don't want to change the display if I can help it).

bitmap generation code:

```
private void SweepPresVisCopyChart(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var chart = (PresVisControl)((ContextMenu)((MenuItem)sender).Parent).PlacementTarget;

   var scrlvw= (ScrollViewer)chart.Parent;

   var oldHO = scrlvw.HorizontalOffset;

   scrlvw.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(0);

   RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)chart.RenderSize.Width, (int)chart.RenderSize.Height, 192, 192, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

   bmp.Render(chart);

   var usebmp = toImg(bmp);

   Clipboard.SetImage(ConvertToBitmapSource(usebmp));

   scrlvw.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(oldHO);
}
```

XAML:

```
            <ScrollViewer Name="scViewer" Loaded="ScrollViewer_Loaded" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="ScrollViewer_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseMove="ScrollViewer_MouseMove" MouseLeftButtonUp="ScrollViewer_MouseLeftButtonUp" PreviewMouseWheel="ScrollViewer_PreviewMouseWheel">
                <ScrollViewer.LayoutTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ViewZoom}" ScaleY="{Binding ViewZoom}"/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </ScrollViewer.LayoutTransform>

                <Controls:PresVisControl  HideDataPoints="True" CPVisibilityWithRefresh="Hidden" CPVisibility="Hidden" ImagePath="{Binding PresTapImagePath}" NearestTap="{Binding NearestTapToClick, Mode=TwoWay}"  Margin="5" PresTapDataGreen="{Binding lclPresTapDataGreen}" PresTapDataRed="{Binding lclPresTapDataRed}" PresTapDataScale="{Binding lclPresTapDataScale}" PresTapDataGrey="{Binding lclPresTapDataGrey}">
                    <Controls:PresVisControl.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Click="MenuItem_Click">
                                <MenuItem.Header>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBlock Text="Show "/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding NearestTapToClick, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                                        <TextBlock Text=" on CM Chart"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </MenuItem.Header>
                            </MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem Header="Set as CA Reference" Command="{Binding HandleCARefCommand}"/>
                            <Separator/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Copy chart" Click="SweepPresVisCopyChart"/>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Controls:PresVisControl.ContextMenu>
                </Controls:PresVisControl>
            </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55546728/1136211

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RenderTargetBitmap Image Sliding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55545728/rendertargetbitmap-image-sliding)

Comment: That image sliding post was just what I needed! Thx