# Quality of screenshot

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net

In one of my previous questions I asked how I could take a screenshot of everything  that's inside of a `ScrollViewer`, not just what's visible in the `ViewPort`. After a lot of trying I found myself an answer, but unfortunately this answer raises another question.

Have a look at this example code:

ItemViewModel.vb (just a simple view model for my `TreeViewItem`s):

```
Public Class ItemViewModel
    Public Property Text As String
    Public Property Items As New ObservableCollection(Of ItemViewModel)
End Class
```

ViewModel.vb (the view model for my main window, creating some items in the constructor):

```
Public Class ViewModel
    Public Property Items As New ObservableCollection(Of ItemViewModel)

    Private Const levels As Integer = 3

    Public Sub New()
        Dim item1 As ItemViewModel
        Dim item2 As ItemViewModel
        Dim item3 As ItemViewModel

        For index1 As Integer = 1 To levels
            item1 = New ItemViewModel With {.Text = String.Format("Node {0} - {1}", index1, Guid.NewGuid.ToString)}
            Me.Items.Add(item1)

            For index2 As Integer = 1 To levels
                item2 = New ItemViewModel With {.Text = String.Format("Node {0}.{1} - {2}", index1, index2, Guid.NewGuid.ToString)}
                item1.Items.Add(item2)

                For index3 As Integer = 1 To levels
                    item3 = New ItemViewModel With {.Text = String.Format("Node {0}.{1}.{2} - {3}", index1, index2, index3, Guid.NewGuid.ToString)}
                    item2.Items.Add(item3)
                Next index3
            Next index2
        Next index1
    End Sub

End Class
```

MainWindow.xaml (the main window itself, showing a `TreeView`):

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ScreenshotTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="200" Width="300" KeyDown="Window_KeyDown">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <TreeView x:Name="Tree" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ItemViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="1">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" Margin="2" />
                </Border>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" />
            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </TreeView>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.vb (code-behind for the main window, here's where the "useful" code sits):

```
Class MainWindow

    Private Sub Window_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)
        Dim panel As StackPanel

        If e.Key <> Key.P Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        panel = GetFirstChildOfType(Of StackPanel)(Me.Tree)
        panel.Background = Brushes.White
        panel.UpdateLayout()

        Me.CaptureScreen(panel, "C:\Temp\Screenshot.png")
    End Sub

    Private Shared Function GetFirstChildOfType(Of T As DependencyObject)(obj As DependencyObject) As T
        Dim result As T
        Dim child As DependencyObject

        If (obj Is Nothing) Then
            Return Nothing
        End If

        If (VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj) = 0) Then
            Return Nothing
        End If

        For index As Integer = 0 To VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj)
            child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, index)
            result = TryCast(child, T)

            If (result Is Nothing) Then
                result = GetFirstChildOfType(Of T)(child)
            End If

            If (result IsNot Nothing) Then
                Return result
            End If
        Next index

        Return Nothing
    End Function

    Private Sub CaptureScreen(source As UIElement, filename As String)
        Dim height As Double
        Dim renderHeight As Double
        Dim width As Double
        Dim renderWidth As Double
        Dim renderTarget As RenderTargetBitmap
        Dim vb As VisualBrush
        Dim dv As DrawingVisual
        Dim encoder As PngBitmapEncoder

        Try
            height = source.RenderSize.Height
            renderHeight = height
            width = source.RenderSize.Width
            renderWidth = width

            renderTarget = New RenderTargetBitmap(Convert.ToInt32(renderWidth), Convert.ToInt32(renderHeight), 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32)
            vb = New VisualBrush(source)

            dv = New DrawingVisual

            Using dc As DrawingContext = dv.RenderOpen
                dc.DrawRectangle(vb, Nothing, New Rect(New Point(0, 0), New Point(width, height)))
            End Using

            renderTarget.Render(dv)

            encoder = New PngBitmapEncoder
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderTarget))

            Using fs As IO.FileStream = New IO.FileStream(filename, IO.FileMode.Create, IO.FileAccess.Write)
                encoder.Save(fs)
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            Stop
        End Try
    End Sub

End Class
```

If you run this program, you'll see a `TreeView` with a few items, and if you press P a screenshot of the content of the `TreeView` is taken and saved as "C:\Temp\Screenshot.png".

So far, so good, the screenshot roughly looks like what's seen on screen (quality-wise). If you view the created png file for instance in IrfanView (at 100% size), everything is readable.

But if I create more and more items (increasing the `levels` constant to 5 and then to 7), the quality of the picture is getting worse, at `levels`=7 one can't read anything on the screenshot.

Does anyone know what is happening here and how I could fix that? I'm fine with answers in C# as well.

Here's a few screenshots to visualize my problem:

Main window on screen

[image: Main window on screen]

Screenshot with levels=3

[image: Screenshot with levels=3]

Screenshot with levels=5

[image: Screenshot with levels=5]

Screenshot with levels=7

[image: Screenshot with levels=7]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not that proficient with WPF, but creating a `VisualBrush` to draw the items seems wrong. So instead of the code using the `VisualBrush` and `DrawingVisual`, just use `renderTarget.Render(source)`.

```
Private Sub CaptureScreen(source As UIElement, filename As String)
  Dim height As Double
  Dim renderHeight As Double
  Dim width As Double
  Dim renderWidth As Double
  Dim renderTarget As RenderTargetBitmap
  Dim vb As VisualBrush
  Dim dv As DrawingVisual
  Dim encoder As PngBitmapEncoder

  Try
    height = source.RenderSize.Height
    Debug.Print(height.ToString)
    renderHeight = height
    width = source.RenderSize.Width
    renderWidth = width

    renderTarget = New RenderTargetBitmap(Convert.ToInt32(renderWidth), Convert.ToInt32(renderHeight), 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32)
    renderTarget.Render(source)

    encoder = New PngBitmapEncoder
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderTarget))

    Using fs As IO.FileStream = New IO.FileStream(filename, IO.FileMode.Create, IO.FileAccess.Write)
      encoder.Save(fs)
    End Using
  Catch ex As Exception
    Stop
  End Try
End Sub
```

This seems to work well for me.

Comment: You are right, getting rid of the `VisualBrush` and the `DrawingContext` worked. I don't know anymore why I used them in the first place. It was probably a left-over from my countless trials. Thank you.

Comment: Using a DrawingVisual may be necessary when the rendered control has a non-zero VisualOffset, e.g. by using Margins. See e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55546728/1136211.